# MutationObserver on Vue Component

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to listen for my main component size being changed, so I can run some code. However the console log isn't being fired at all however I can't see what I have done wrong :S

```js
mounted() {
    new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
        console.log(mutationsList);
    }).observe(this.$el, { attributes: true });
}
```

Can anyone see the issue? It should fire when I resize the window as this resizes the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MutationObserver is an api designed to observe direct DOM updates.
Since a window resize is not a proper DOM update, it won't work.

I suggest you use a more basic approach:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => console.log(event))
```

Your code can only work with MutationObserver if your component size (width, height) is set directly in an attribute like `style` in the HTML since you use the config `{ attributes: true }`.

```
<div style="width: 200px">content</div>
```